# Sidekiq causes StackLevelTooDeep error when running

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sidekiq

Here is my `Sidekiq` setup:

Controller that calls my background process

```
BackgroundStatCalculator.perform_async @game.athlete.id, @game.id, current_athlete_sport.id
```

Sidekiq worker:

```
class BackgroundStatCalculator
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(user_id, game_id, sport_id)
    sport = Sport.find sport_id
    sport.stat_type_categories.each do |st_cat|
      calc = "StatCalculators::#{st_cat.name}".constantize.new(user_id, game_id)
      calc.run_calculations
    end
  end
end
```

Calculator:

```
module StatCalculators
  class Passing
    def initialize(user_id, game_id)
      @user = User.find(user_id)
      @game = Game.find(game_id)
    end

    def save_completion_percentage
      completions = Stat.for_type("Completions").for_user(@user).sum(:float_value)
      attempts = Stat.for_type("Pass Attempts").for_user(@user).sum(:float_value)
      value = completions/attempts
      stat = Stat.new(value: value, game_id: @game.id, athlete_id: @user.id, float_value: value)
      stat.save(validate: false)
    end

    def run_calculations
      klass = self.class
      klass.instance_methods(false).each do |method|
        klass.instance_method(method).bind(self).call
      end
    end
  end
end
```

StackTrace:

```
2013-06-07T17:55:34Z 73625 TID-ov6v51sww BackgroundStatCalculator JID-5bab7cec30523a4b12dd6438 INFO: fail: 5.155 sec
2013-06-07T17:55:34Z 73625 TID-ov6v51sww WARN: {"retry"=>true, "queue"=>"default", "class"=>"BackgroundStatCalculator", "args"=>[58, 68, 6], "jid"=>"5bab7cec30523a4b12dd6438", "error_message"=>"stack level too deep", "error_class"=>"SystemStackError", "failed_at"=>"2013-06-07T17:42:01Z", "retry_count"=>5, "retried_at"=>2013-06-07 17:55:34 UTC}
2013-06-07T17:55:34Z 73625 TID-ov6v51sww WARN: stack level too deep
2013-06-07T17:55:34Z 73625 TID-ov6v51sww WARN: /Users/dennismonsewicz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/sidekiq-2.7.4/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:88
```

For some reason when `.perform_async` is called, it doesn't just execute once and done... it dumps 100s of rows into my database.

Anyone run into this issue before? I am fairly new to working with Sidekiq, so my apologies for my ignorance here

Comment: Does this happen when you run the job synchronously? Meaning, can you replicate the issue doing `BackgroundStatCalculator.new` then instead of `perform_async` use `perform` on the instance.

Comment: It works just fine using `perform` its only when `perform_async` is called that it dumps 100s of records into the database

Comment: Can you post the backtrace?

Comment: Ok, I restarted my rails server and I no longer am getting the `StackLevelTooDeep` issue... its just dumping 100s of records into my database for some reason... again, this doesn't happen when `.perform` is ran

Comment: Try checking your redis queue. It might have a few jobs backed up.

Comment: @LeoCorrea - I take that back.. I was able to locate the stack trace.. my question is updated

Answer (score 2):

You've created an infinite loop of calls which is causing the stack to overflow.

Your `run_calculations` method calls every instance method on the object it's on, which includes `run_calculations`.  You need to filter out this method from the list or better yet, find a way to white-list only the calculation methods you want to call.  Perhaps using a prefix like "calculate_".

```
module StatCalculators
  class Passing
    def initialize(user_id, game_id)
      ...
    end

    def calculate_completion_percentage
       ...
    end

    def run_calculations
      klass = self.class
      calculation_methods = klass.instance_methods(false).select do |method|
         method.to_s.match /calculate_/
      end
      calculation_methods.each do |method|
        klass.instance_method(method).bind(self).call
      end
    end
  end
end
```